# JSON.stringify structure is wrong

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON string:

```
[{"spawnIndex":0,"name":"name","surname":"surname","level":0,"cash":0,"bank":0,"gender":"male","fraction":"fraction","family":"family","playedTime":"0","ban":{}}]
```

which is created in the following way:

```
let charackters = [];

charackters.push({
    spawnIndex: 0,
    name: 'name',
    surname: 'surname',
    level: 0,
    cash: 0,
    bank: 0,
    gender: 'male',
    fraction: 'fraction',
    family: 'family',
    playedTime: '0',
    ban: {}
});

let string = JSON.stringify(charackters);
```

My problem is now that I need the string to look like this:

```
{
    characters: [{
        spawnIndex: 0,
        name: 'name',
        surname: 'surname',
        level: 0,
        cash: 0,
        bank: 0,
        gender: 'male',
        fraction: 'fraction',
        family: 'family',
        playedTime: '0',
        ban: {}
    }]
}
```

How could I archive this?

Comment: By reading the docs: [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#parameters)

Comment: Why are you pushing it into an array if you want want the array in your string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` working is simple and it will work as expected in your case. But on top of it you need a different structure of object after parsing back.

so you could simply do

```js
let charackters = [];

charackters.push({
    spawnIndex: 0,
    name: 'name',
    surname: 'surname',
    level: 0,
    cash: 0,
    bank: 0,
    gender: 'male',
    fraction: 'fraction',
    family: 'family',
    playedTime: '0',
    ban: {}
});

let newObject = {
  characters: charackters
}

let string = JSON.stringify(newObject);

console.log(JSON.parse(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the array in an object with the `characters` property you're looking for.

```
let string = JSON.stringify({characters: charackters});
```

The following example is set to use spacing so the output is more readable:

```js
let charackters = [];

charackters.push({
    spawnIndex: 0,
    name: 'name',
    surname: 'surname',
    level: 0,
    cash: 0,
    bank: 0,
    gender: 'male',
    fraction: 'fraction',
    family: 'family',
    playedTime: '0',
    ban: {}
});

let string = JSON.stringify({characters: charackters}, undefined, 2);
console.log(string);
```